# Wifi connection established but not able to access internet

Tags: wireless

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and having a problem with wifi Connection. I am able to connect to other visible wifi networks and access the internet. But when I connect to my own wifi router, it shows "connection established" but I cannot access internet. Browser just shows connecting. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

[image]

```
apurv@apurv-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z400-Touch:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0888] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4262]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Hi There! Once you're connected to the wireless network (that is having issue), can you open up a terminal, type these commands one by one, `ifconfig -a`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf`,  `route -n`, `ping 8.8.8.8` then post the results by [**editing**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/818543/edit) your question.

Comment: @AzkerM I have attached the images

Comment: @user3761761 Please don’t post images of text. Copy the text and paste it into the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Melebius - I don't see an issue on that. Any medium that produce useful information, why not then? BTW, **@user376176**, quite strange that your DNS is not updating properly when you connect to the said network. Is it just only to this device or all are the same?

Comment: @AzkerM See https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals, for example. In this case, it would be at least better for extending (currently Pilot6 is asking for another listing) and wouldn’t miss a part of the first character of every line.

Comment: @Melebius Well, OP's concern on **meta** and the answer, both are debatable. I agree on both cased. Meanwhile, these type of questions are pretty common on the other hand. IMHO, yes there are concerns but I would still support. :)

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited my ques as you asked.
 This is for all the devices. Internet worked on other devices when tried with proxy. I am still not able to fix the issue